# VBA - import n lines from multiple text files

Tags: excel, vba, import, text-files

I have a piece of code that imports multiple text files with some data I need. I'd like to change it a bit - I want it to stop reading the file after reaching line number 50 in the text file and import only those first 50 lines. Is there a way I could do this? I was thinking about a loop that goes line by line and executes the code until the line number is larger than 50. I figured out a way to write such a loop, however it doesn't split the line into columns and I need that. Also in the way I wrote it it imports only 1 file. I had a code that worked in terms of reading multiple files and dividing them into columns, but I couldn't make it to end after 50 lines. I used QueryTables for this. Maybe instead of doing that loop I could draw on that?

Here's what I have - it obviously doesn't work:

```
Sub RT()
Dim fso As Object
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant
Dim rec As String
Dim i As Long
Dim txtfilnumber As Integer
Dim FileNumber
Dim txtline As String
    i = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
             (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
              MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

With ActiveSheet
    .Cells.ClearContents
    For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
        importrow = 2 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(txtfile)
            Do While Not .AtEndOfStream
                If .line < 50 Then
                    Cells(.line, 1).Value = .ReadLine
                Else: Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    Next txtfile

    For Each qt In .QueryTables
       qt.Delete
    Next qt

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how I can approach this? I'm really new at this and still very lost. I'm pretty much stabbing in the dark here. If you could give me a tip on what I can do or what function to use I'll be really thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code imports more that one file, however, it always overwrite the content of a previous imported file. You need to add `importrow` to the cell address.

When you want to split the text into several columns, you need to know how to split it. Do you have a field separator (Tab, Semicolon, comma)? Fixed length?

The following code will split the text into several cells assuming the semicolon as separator. It may be a little bit slow, but you will get the idea.

```
Do While Not .AtEndOfStream
   If .line > 50 Then Exit Do
  
   Dim txtLine as String, tokens() as String, i as long
   txtLine = .ReadLine
   tokens = Split(txtLine, ";")
   For i = 0 to UBound(tokens)
       .Cells(importrow + .line, i+1).Value = tokens(i)
   Next i
Loop
```

Comment: FunThomas, thanks a ton! I had to slightly adjust it to my code and change the separator and it works! I can rest peacefully now. Thanks again!